# Problems getting PDO (or mysqli extension) to run queries on database

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo, mysqli

The main problem is that for the past week I have not been able to get my script to run queries.

I'm running wamp apache 2.4, php 5.5 and mysql 5.6

```
  if ($flag == true) {

    //try to connect to db with given parameters
    // minimal validation to make sure no input was sent in error so now i can begin code to connect to database 
    // using the pdo php data object extension

    print 'all input validated';

    $host= "127.0.0.1";
    $db_name ="theturnbuckle";
    $port= "3306";
    $dbusername= 'root';
    $dbpassword= '';

    //registration details including host, port and database name
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$db_name;";

    //error handling for connection
    try {
       $db = new PDO($dsn, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
       //if no proplems flag a variable for connection status which is to be used later.
       $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
       $db->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


       //first query to test that the username is not in the database.
       $username = $_POST['username'];
       $userquery = "SELECT username  FROM registation_view WHERE username = :username" ; 


       //second query to test for existing email
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $emailquery = "SELECT email FROM registation_view WHERE email = :email";

       //preparing statement, binding html input to variables to be used in the prepared statement.
       $db = new PDO($dsn, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
       $stmt = $db->prepare($userquery);
       $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 15);

        //execute the query in variable
        $stmt->execute($userquery);
        if ($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0){
            print 'Sorry ' .$username . 'is already in use please try another';
        }//else the username is not is use as fetchColumn is null or the if is false
        else {$registerprocess === true;}


        $db = new PDO($dsn, $dbusername, $dbpassword);  
        $stmt = $db->prepare($emailquery);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR, 15);

        $stmt->execute($emailquery);
         if ($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0){
             print 'Sorry ' .$_POST['email'] . 'is already in use please try another';
             $registerprocess === false;
         }//else the email is not is use as fetchColumn is not > 0 so the registration proceeds.
         else {$registerprocess === true;}

         // catch (PDOException $e){
         //die("Unable to run query: " . $e->getMessage());}


         if ($registerprocess === true) {       
              //username and email are not on record so i am free to INSERT data into database
              $query = "INSERT INTO registration_view (username, password, email, gender, date_of_birth, joindate)
              VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

              $joindate = now();
              $date_of_birth = $_POST['day'] . $_POST['month'] . $_POST['year'];

              $stmt->prepare($query);
              $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20) ;
              $stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20) ;
              $stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20) ;
              $stmt->bindParam(4, $_POST['gender']) ;
              $stmt->bindParam(5, $date_of_birth) ;
              $stmt->bindParam(6, $joindate) ;

              $stmt->execute();

              print ' Welcome ' .$username . 'you are now registered';
       }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage());
    }

}//INPUT VALIDATION IF
```

This is my code, the first flag is to continue on once data validation has been successful that much has worked and the print 'validation'; confirms this.

I'm sure that the $dsn is not in error as an error was displayed previously when it was wrapped in single quotes and now no such errors are being displayed.

While i'm open to the code being a mess i've also been going through the php.ini my.ini and apache.config but as said no luck for a week.

The only things i can add of any help (or at least maybe a lead) is some errors for the apache and php error logs.

Apache displays this from when i try to run the script from local host.

```
[Mon Dec 29 12:49:13.855653 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 3632:tid 964] [client ::1:49206] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: http://localhost/theturnbuckle/
```

And php display this, although i have reinstalled the apche server since and before the installation i moved the php_intl.dll and phpldap.dll to another folder in wamp and these errors went away. (not even sure if that is the best practice)

```
[24-Dec-2014 12:00:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
```

in Unknown on line 0

```
[24-Dec-2014 12:00:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
```

in Unknown on line 0

I uncommented out some of the mysql server variables.

```
innodb_data_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
innodb_log_arch_dir = C:\mysql\data/
```

And finally i checked out some php.ini server variables to try and help the situation, display errors is on.

All php extensions seem to be installed such as php_pdo_mysql and php_mysqli.

But at the end of the day i'm floundering in the dark.

Comment: possibly dumb question: do the files `c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll` and `c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll` exist?

Comment: Can you confirm that [mysqlnd](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/) is installed?

Comment: Is there a typo in `registation_view`? The correct spelling should be `registration_view`

Comment: Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $ This was displayed in phpinfo but i'll look into it some more.

Comment: php_intl.dll and php_ldap.dll extensions seem to be found now. Typo fixed and still researching more on mysqlnd.

Comment: in phpinfo it says that mysqlnd is enabled.                            mysqlnd
mysqlnd enabled
Version  mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $
Compression  supported
core SSL  supported
extended SSL  not supported
Command buffer size  4096
Read buffer size  32768
Read timeout  31536000
Collecting statistics  Yes
Collecting memory statistics  Yes
Tracing  n/a
Loaded plugins  mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password
API Extensions  mysql,mysqli,pdo_mysql

Answer (score 0):

You have two warnings :

```
[24-Dec-2014 12:00:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
```

and

```
[24-Dec-2014 12:00:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
```

So just install or enable these extensions.

Comment: the extensions are enabled in php.ini and the files are in the directory stated in the error message. someone said that maybe they are not being found and to move them into a directory above, the php5.5.12 directory, this got rid of it previously before i reinstalled wamp a while ago.